# How to change result row into column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have below result set

```
Name  |   ID |  Total |  CityName
--------------------------------
A         1       2        ABC
--------------------------------
B         2       1        XYZ
--------------------------------
C         3       1        ABC
--------------------------------
```

How I can show below result

```
Name |  ID  |   ABC |  XYZ
---------------------------
A       1        2      0
---------------------------
B       2        0      1
---------------------------
C       3        1      0
---------------------------
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. And note that this is something of a frequently asked question

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select name, id, max(case when CityName='ABC' then total else 0 end) as ABC
max(case when CityName='XYZ' then total else 0 end) as XYZ
from tablename
group by name,id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like a subquery, or procedure would be a good idea.
Something like:

```
select Name,ID,
(select Total from tets where CityName ='ABC' and Id = t.Id) as 'ABC',
(select Total from tets where CityName ='XYZ' and Id = t.Id) as 'XYZ'
from tets t
```

Comment: fa06 answers seems more elegant and will take care of returning "0" when it's needed ;)